# Can a 737 yaw while parked due to wind?

Tags: aircraft-physics, yaw

How much wind force is required to push/rotate a 737 sideways while parked?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't really understand your question. Are you asking how strong the wind would have to be, to move a parked 737 sideways? Or how much the vertical stabilizer of a parked 737 flexes in the wind? Or something else?

Comment: Are you asking how much the aircraft could physically move, or how much force is applied to the aircraft by the wind? The wind loading is fairly straightforward, you can neglect the wings and just use the cross section of the fuselage and vertical tail. If you want to know if this would move the aircraft you need to know the coefficient of friction of the tires/pavement and the weight of the aircraft to figure out how much force would be necessary to overcome friction.

Comment: Hi thanks, yes a bit of a strange one but basically take a stationary 737 and a  full crosswind of say 10 knots... the vertical stab being 26.44 m2 in area and the force the wind would have on it in a turning effect, how could you work out how far left or right the aircraft tail or nose could be turned or moved by the wind, thanks

Comment: Unless the nose wheel is on ice or a very low friction surface, this isn't an easy answer. If you run through the calculations though, you'll find it takes a very significant cross wind to move the aircraft nose (skid on pavement), probably in the order of 75+ knots. It also depends on loading, if the aircraft is loaded nose-light, it will be easier, but if its loaded nose heavy, it will be harder.

Comment: On ice? [Easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrl3ex7w6nA). :)

Comment: The answer will depend on wheel loading and the coefficient of friction for the supporting surface.

Comment: @ymb1 - Everyone else is running away, and the guy in blue is trying to push it back. Major props for the effort, man in blue!

Comment: Slightly related (with a B747): "The next day the plane was found to have also rotated about 45 degrees from its original position." https://youtu.be/cHhZwvdRR5c

Answer (score 2):

From own experience some years ago an empty B737-300 with ~2500kg fuel in the tanks can be moved by crosswinds as low as 55kt. Surface was a regular dry concrete apron with no slope. That's why my companys GOM (ground operation manual) required ballasting the aircraft with max fuel in high winds and chocks on the main wheels both sides.